# Why aren't my contacts rendering to my home page?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm trying to create a simple contacts list (aka rolodex) where a user can create a new contact and be redirected to the home page that renders the new contact. Right now I'm getting 'cannot read property contacts' at 'this.setState({ contacts: this.state.contacts.concat([contact]) });'

Any help is appreciated!

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import New from "./new";
import Home from "./home";
import Contact from "./contact";
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      contacts: []
    };
  }

  addContact(contact) {
    this.setState({ contacts: this.state.contacts.concat([contact]) });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <BrowserRouter>
        <div>
          <Switch>
            <Route
              exact
              path="/newcontact"
              render={() => <New addContact={this.addContact} />}
            />
            <Route
              exact
              path="/home"
              render={() => <Home contacts={this.state.contacts} />}
            />

            <Route
              path="/contact"
              render={() => <Contact contacts={this.state.contacts} />}
            />
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

New.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

// import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class New extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      name: "",
      image_url: "",
      email: "",
      phone_number: ""
    };

    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
  }

  handleClick() {
    const generateId = () => Math.round(Math.random() * 100000000);
    const contact = {
      id: generateId(),
      name: this.state.name,
      image_url: this.state.image_url,
      email: this.state.email,
      phone_number: this.state.phone_number
    };

    this.props.addContact(contact);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>New Contact info</h1>
        <form name="newContact">
          <input
            name="name"
            value={this.state.name}
            onChange={event => this.setState({ name: event.target.value })}
            placeholder="Contact Name"
          />
          <input
            name="image_url"
            value={this.state.image_url}
            onChange={event => this.setState({ image_url: event.target.value })}
            placeholder="Photo Url"
          />
          <input
            name="email"
            value={this.state.email}
            onChange={event => this.setState({ email: event.target.value })}
            placeholder="Email Address"
          />
          <input
            name="phone_number"
            value={this.state.phone_number}
            onChange={event =>
              this.setState({ phone_number: event.target.value })
            }
            placeholder="Phone Number"
          />
        </form>

        <Link to={`/home`}>
          <button onClick={this.handleClick}>Submit New Contact</button>
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

// Home.propTypes = {
//   name: React.PropTypes.string,
//   image_url: React.PropTypes.string,
//   email: React.PropTypes.string,
//   phone_number: React.PropTypes.number
// };

export default New;

//grab input fields and change new contact's state, then push that to contacts list's state.
//prop types validate fields
```

home.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import New from "./new";

class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { contacts } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Contact List</h1>
        <div>{this.props.contacts}</div>

        <Link to={`/newcontact`}>
          <button>Add New Contact</button>
        </Link>

        <Link to={`/contact`}>
          <button>Contact ID</button>
        </Link>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
//map id key to individual contact?
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the issue of 'this'. Try bind 'this' to the method named 'addContact' like what you have do to the method 'handleClick'. More details why this is necessary(I'm not sure if you need since you did some in your code) please check https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html

ps. A working sample of the issue always helps. It's pretty easy by using online service like https://codesandbox.io/.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use the element keys in the contact array to access it.  {this.props.contacts[0]} to access the ID